# Typscript: Gernic types mixed with specifc

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I want to read from a CSV file different articles. The header looks like e.g.

```
"verf.", Bestellnummer", "Name", "Notiz",
```

I'm not sure at which position the field appears, i.e. I want to set the `colPos` dynamically. Additonally I don't want to be dependent on German or English labels, i.e. I want to provide predefined fixed set for the one or the other usage. Therefore I thought have an interface like

```
export interface foodFileStructure<T > {
    colName: string;
    colType: T;
    colPos: number;
}
```

and a more or less generic Article like

```
export interface FoodsoftArticleGeneric {
    available: foodFileStructure<boolean>;
    id: foodFileStructure<number | undefined>; 
    name: foodFileStructure<string>;
    note: foodFileStructure<string>;
}
```

and reading one row of `data:FoodsoftArticleGeneric` which is either of type `German` or `English`.

I struggle how to set now the specfics, e.g. for column `Notiz`. This would be of type `string`. I want to have `FoodsoftArticleGerman` with `colName` = `Notiz` and a `FoodsoftArticleEnglish` with `colName`=`Note`.

So, basically `colName` and `colType` are fixed (hardcoded) while `colPos` would be set dynamically when using an instance of `FoodsoftArticleGerman` (or `FoodsoftArticleEnglish`).

I know I can define them as `const` with the specific value. But I have no clue how to define a Generic with specific value.

Comment: Some parts of the question are not very clear, but it seems to me that what you want is two *instantiations* of the `FoodsoftArticleGeneric`. Using structural typing, it could be: `const foodsoftArticleGerman: FoodsoftArticleGeneric = { note: { colName: 'Notiz', filetype: '???', colPos: 3 } as foodFileStructure<string>, ... }`. One unclear thing is what you expect in the `filetype`. Another unclear thing is whether you want to provide the `colName` and the system reads the `colpos`, in which case *the system* will create the `FoodsoftArticleGeneric`, not you.

Comment: I've updated my question and hopefully made it little bit more clear what I try to achieve. If still unclear please ask again - thx.

Comment: I'm trying to understand the question: • Could you provide a full [mre] that demonstrates what's going on when pasted into a standalone IDE?  This should include enough input and desired output for pin down the intended behavior. • Interfaces should start with a capital letter. • Parts of the question that would make more sense with a working knowledge of German should probably be rephrased into something that uses English instead or in addition (e.g., is "Bestellnummer" the German label for "id"? Readers probably shouldn't be spending time thinking about things like that).

Comment: @jcalz I don't understand your respone. How would you like to have a MWE when I don't know how to set it up? What do you expect? AND rephrasing German words to English - how do think I address mutlilang problem? US-English vs UK-English? This won't make much sense either. So what do request for clarifications except capital letter in Interface? I would be really curious if you could specify it more precisely.

Comment: • It looks like you know how you want to write the code if it were just JS, but are having trouble coming up with the right typings for it; if so, a [mre] could be a demonstration of the JS code that does what you want.

Comment: • Your example code doesn't need to mimic your actual problem domain; you could be translating between two different English representations of the fields (e.g., `["available", "id", "name", "note"]` vs `["theName", "idNumber", "noteField", "isAvailable"]`); but if you can't come up with a way to do that, it might be helpful for you to give a short glossary of German terms at the top.  Note that the JS [mre] would probably also give this info, since presumably you have a mapping object of labels to field names somewhere.

Comment: to your last comment: I did so as you requested already with the naming of `Notiz` - therefore I still don't understand. and to your previous one: you are requesting similar thing like how a building looks like when you want to layout the basics.  How you want to give a JS about Generics you don't have an idea how to make the Generics?

Comment: I suppose we can't communicate effectively with each other so I will disengage now.  Good luck!